# Invite twitter friends to site?

Tags: twitter, twitter-oauth

Does twitter have something similar to facebook application invite pop-up?

In facebook you can write this:

```
  FB.init({
    appId  : 'xxx',
    status : true,
    cookie : true,
    oauth: true
  });

  FB.ui({
        method: 'apprequests',
        message: 'My Great Request',
        data: '<?php echo $data; ?>'
    }, requestCallback);
```

And it will pop-up dialog where you can select twitter friends, and send invitations to them, and then when invite is accepted with API you can find data to redirect them to site...

Is this somehow possible with twitter?

Does twitter have invite pop-up like facebook?
or maybe sending multiple messages to selected users pop-up?

Comment: Did you find any solution regarding this problem ?

Answer (score 6):

Twitter does not provide such an invite mechanism. You have two options.

1. [POST statuses/update](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/post/statuses/update) to create a general tweet that everyone following the user will see.
2. [POST direct_messages/new](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/post/direct_messages/new) to send a private message to a specific follower.

Be carful however, because posting excessively to either will get your users and your application suspended.

Answer (score 0):

Now twitter has the api by which we can get the contacts if a user. check this-[twitter api](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/friends/list)

Answer (score 0):

Just for someone passing by, right now Twitter has `App Card` which represent mobile applications on Twitter and to drive installs. It allow `name`, `description` and `icon`. It is not exactly like `inviting` on Facebook. However, it drive user to install the app easier please checkout the link.

https://dev.twitter.com/cards/types/app