# Invite Twitter friends for Android app

Tags: android, twitter, invite

How can I invite my Twitter friends/Followers for using my Android app? For doing the same thing in Facebook I am using App Invite to notify my friends.
Is there any way to do this with Twitter Kit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Twitter does not provide such an invite mechanism. You have two options:

- `POST statuses/update` to create a general tweet that everyone following the user will see.
- `POST direct_messages/new` to send a private message to a specific follower.

Be careful however, because posting excessively to either will get your users and your application suspended.

Reference: [Invite twitter friends to site?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7895138/invite-twitter-friends-to-site)

Comment: Thank you. However I see [Invite twitter friends to site?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7895138/invite-twitter-friends-to-site) was answered 3 years ago

Comment: I think it still holds its value; You can check developer documentation here. https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/post/direct_messages/new